# Best Linux Graphics Card drivers for a Dell M1210 / Nvidia GeForce Go 7400?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, drivers, nvidia-geforce, ubuntu-unity

I've tried both Nouveau and the NVIDIA Binary Blob, and both are terrible in terms of performance, lag and graphics corruption. The binary also doesn't support the native resolution in console mode and requires you to use nvidia-xsettings to change anything.
Both have been blacklisted for Ubuntu Unity shell as far as I can tell. What am I to do with the graphics drivers on this PC?

Comment: I think this [LINK](http://imaging.ugent.be/mr/Suse/suse-m1210.html) is useful for you.

Comment: Are you using the NVIDIA binary drivers packaged with Ubuntu, or the installer from NVIDIA?

Answer (score 0):

Your best option would be to search for ubuntu recommended nvidia drivers via `synaptic package manager`. Look for synaptic package manager in your install and if it doesn't exist you need to install it using `sudo apt-get install synaptic` via terminal. I think `nvidia-glx` will be the right one for you. Open synaptic manager and search,install both `nvidia-glx` and `nvidia-xconfig`. After that run `sudo nvidia-xconfig` using terminal and go for a reboot. And make sure you blacklist the other ones.

Comment: I should add, there is a package called `nvidia-detect` available via synaptic. Install it, and run `sudo nvidia-detect` in terminal before you follow what i said above. It will suggest the right driver for you. It should be `nvidia-glx`.

Comment: nvidia-detect doesn't seem to exist in the repos, and nvidia-detector returns none

Comment: Have you gone to `additional drivers` section to look for a suggested driver? Also take a look at this thread. It suggests a working driver. http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1771806

Comment: You should also try your luck with nvidia-glx. Assuming you know how to get back if it goes blank, try installing it via command line. `sudo apt-get install nvidia-glx nvidia-xconfig` and run `sudo nvidia-xconfig`. reboot.

Answer (score 0):

Well. Working with Ubuntu at work, but it is headless. At home I choose to comile every grain myself with Gentoo. Just came back from nouveau to nvidia legacy driver, due to the lack of speed. For official driver, you have to grab a legacy driver. Official legacy driver for Nvidia 7400 Go currently is version 304.x. It's still being updated so won't say 304.137 which is version I use, but get a 304 with a high revision to avoid problems (http://www.nvidia.com/object/unix.html). Also keep you bios updated (Just see if it is). On Gentoo I also have to disable/enable the right accelerarion. VDPAU is only supported on PureVideo able cards (Available on most or all Series 8 and beyond). VAAPI should be avaiailable for the 7400. There are wiki on these, so I'll avoid explainations what it stands for. I have a Nvidia G72M/Nvidia 7400 Go GPU [use lspci command to see yours] on my old laptop, which is what I base most of the info from.